# nodejs run cd and zip command always failed

Tags: node.js, webpack

all. I ran into a strange situation.
os: macOS

I can run `zip -r test.zip *` in the console. Then I try to do this in a script with nodejs and a plugin called 'webpackshellplugin-next'. I import this plugin and then call it to run script when the build process exits. I try to zip some files in the ./build/ folder, just something like the screenshot.

[image]

I failed in the 2nd step, to `cd ./build && ...`, because I see the console shows `no such file or directory` when it tries to `cp ./build/xxx.mpk` to other directory. I check the `./build` directory, the xxx.mpk file is not generated.

Can I examine why this script failed?

Comment: Please don't use the `script` tag. It means *nothing at all*. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. The tag is so bad it will was deleted in the past and is going to be deleted again very soon

Comment: And post the code itself as text, not images f the code. Images can't be copied, googled, compiled or debugged